# syntax error on mathematical operation postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

I'm trying to declare this function to be used as a trigger:

```
create or replace function atualiza_qtfunc()
returns trigger as 
$f_at_qtfunc$ --f_at_func = função atualiza quantidade funcionários
declare qt integer;
begin

select tabemissora.qtfunc into qt from tabemissora;

if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then 

UṔDATE tabemissora set qtfunc = qt + 1;

elseif (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then

UṔDATE tabemissora set qtfunc = qt - 1;

end if;

end;
$f_at_qtfunc$ language 'plpgsql'
```

But I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UṔDATE"
LINE 12: UṔDATE tabemissora set qtfunc = qt + 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the `UṔDATE` should be `UPDATE` ? That `Ṕ` is the "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P WITH ACUTE", a different character than the common capital P.

Comment: `select tabemissora.qtfunc into qt from tabemissora;` is most probably wrong. You are trying to load the values from ***all*** rows from the table `tabemissora` into a **single** integer value. Also on which table is that trigger defined?

Answer (score 1):

[@ypercube pointed out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123368/syntax-error-on-mathematical-operation-postgresql#comment226720_123368) the immediate cause for the syntax error. But there is a lot more:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.atualiza_qtfunc()
  RETURNS trigger AS 
$f_at_qtfunc$ --f_at_func = função atualiza quantidade funcionários
BEGIN
   CASE TG_OP
   WHEN 'INSERT' THEN 
      UPDATE tabemissora SET qtfunc = qtfunc + 1
      WHERE  some_id = NEW.some_id;  -- reference NEW row
   WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
      UPDATE tabemissora SET qtfunc = qtfunc - 1
      WHERE  some_id = OLD.some_id;  -- reference OLD row
   END CASE;
END
$f_at_qtfunc$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Remove the `SELECT` completely, you can refer to the column itself in the `UPDATE` statement directly.
- Consequently, remove the needless variable declaration altogether.
- **Don't** `UPDATE` without `WHERE` condition, that would alter *all* rows in the table, which is most probably not what you want. io made the command depend on the inserted / deleted row at hand.
- I used `CASE` instead of `IF` to simplify. Optional.
- Don't quote the language name.

Even with the fixed function, your whole approach may be a bad idea in a **multi-user environment**. Multiple concurrent inserts / deletes for the same parent-ID can produce race conditions that this kind of function is not able to resolve. If that can happen, you'd rather do the count after the fact in a view or materialized view and drop the trigger altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I'll only maintain the update without the where case because in this problem the updated table will always contain one row. It is never inserted anything at this table at any moment.

Comment: @WeltenSchann: That makes more sense. Remember to mention essential details in your questions.